# How do I move from the MSVC compiler to GCC on Windows?

Tags: gcc, migration, visual-studio-2010

The reasons I want to move are:

1. Compile speed. About a minute with gcc, 15 minutes with MSVC. Admittedly, the code I'm compiling is a ball of spaghetti, but it is the code I have to work with on a daily basis. Sure, I don't expect gcc would magically take my compile times down to a minute, but I do expect it to compile files a lot faster.
2. Slow debugging: Its been close to a year now, using VS2010 trying to debug on Windows is a nightmare - it is so slow, it is unusable. Yes, I've tried deleting my .suo, closing the autos window, unplugging myself from the network and dancing around a fire three times under the full moon, to no avail.

So my question is: How do I get my code, which makes heavy use of the Windows APIs and MFCs to build on GCC? Rather, what would be the simplest route?

Comment: `#include <windows.h>` (and etc.) usually works. What blew up when you tried it?

Comment: It looks like MFC is the problem. In other words, is there any way to get gcc to successfully build MFCs?

Comment: Hmm, yes that might be more difficult. I'm not sure, I've never actually tried building MFC with GCC. The issue is that MFC was written before C++ became standardized. There's a lot of stuff it does that's no longer idiomatic C++, and GCC probably chokes on it. Microsoft's compiler still supports their extensions for backwards compatibility reasons. Do you really need to use MFC? And if you do, perhaps a better option is figuring out why Microsoft's compiler is so slow for you. It's not slow for me... Not really enough info in the question to diagnose that problem.

Comment: @Carl: look at each preprocessor on the MFC project created by visual studio and try to move them or declare them in your project. have you tried to compile?? if so what was the errors?.

Comment: @Ahmedsafan: MFCs are a Microsoft thing. Visual Studio does not create an MFC project. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Foundation_Class_Library). Making all MFC classes compile under GCC is probably an even bigger effort than trying to not use MFCs in the first place.