# not able to include few header files in dev c++

Tags: header-files, dev-c++

When i include few header files like **#include "afxwin.h" and #include "afxext.h"** in Dev C++, its showing me file not found. Can anyone help me?

Comment: These are MS Visual C++ precompiled headers, and you aren't going to find them in GCC based compilers. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same problem and this worked for me

In filename.cpp, I put: #include "*full path to* filename.h"

When using the file, I had put: #include "*full path to* filename.h" and #include "*full path to* filename.cpp"

Answer (score 0):

These are MS Visual C++ precompiled headers (related to MFC):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precompiled_header

You might get lucky and be able to compile and use them in combination with GCC/Dev-C++, but I wouldn't bet on it (see the third comment on the opening post):

[How do I move from the MSVC compiler to GCC on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9025617/how-do-i-move-from-the-msvc-compiler-to-gcc-on-windows)

Assuming that comment is correct, you won't be able to use MFC on GCC compilers. And because Dev-C++ uses these, you won't be able to use MFC in combination with Dev-C++ either. As an alternative, you could try out a free version of MS Visual Studio to be able to use the headers.